# Google Tag Manager (GTM) intermittently not firing in ASP

Tags: google-analytics, asp-classic, google-tag-manager

The Google Analytics / Conversions / Transactions indicate that the Tag only works sometimes - if I perform the tasks and watch what happens and/or debug it always works but when the public/others do it sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't

The implementation is a step by step, wizard approach, Rental Car Booking. At the end of the process, we store the booking in a database, draw up a Thankyou page, firing te GTM to record the transaction in GA, and we send a confirmation email to the user.

The Setup:
GTM 
Created Tag "Booking Value Transaction" - Type=Universal Analytics, Enabled Display Advert Features, Track Type = Transaction
Added 2 Rules
    Rule Name = "BookNow" - Conditions    {{url}} contains thankyou   + {{event}} contains gtm.dom
    Rule Name = "BookNow_Mobile"  - Conditions   {{url}} contains mobileBooking  + {{event}} contains gtm.dom

ASP page
At the beginning of the

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager - data layer def only -->
<script>
    dataLayer = [{ 
        'transactionId': '',
        'transactionTotal': 0.00}];
        transactionProducts = [{
            'name': '',
            'sku': '', 
            'price': 0.00, 
            'quantity': 0 }];
</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager - data layer def only -->
```

Later in the page various ASP code calls database functions etc to store data and retrieve data for display and builds the data to populate the GTM datalayer 
Eventually it produces the following (with appropriate values set):

```
<script>dataLayer = [{ 'transactionId': '1234', 'transactionTotal': 1000.00}];
transactionProducts = [{'name': 'Some Product Name', 'sku': '5678', 'price': 1000.00, 'quantity': 1 }];
dataLayer.push({'transactionProducts':transactionProducts});</script>
```

Following the above and before the end of the  (because putting it at the top beneath the datalayer definition looked like an issue) the rest of the GTM script is inserted

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<% 'at the bottom of the page because the gtm.DOM async might not be performing like we want %>
<noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-MyGTM_ID" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<script>
    (function(w,d,s,l,i){
   w[l]=w[l]||[];
   w[l].push({'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});
   var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';
   j.async=true;
   j.src='//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;
   f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    }
    )(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-MyGTM_ID');
</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

I have tried all sorts to get to the bottom of this but I am completely stumped.
How do I get this to reliably fire all the time?

Comment: This is client side code - I can't see any classic asp apart from a comment

Comment: The ASP code does a Response.Write the "<script>dataLayer = ...." etc injecting the various variables to write the values display in my example above.

Answer (score 2):

The dataLayer.push() only gets the data into the dataLayer; it does not send the data to Google. You need some sort of tag that fires to carry the dataLayer data with it.

Usually this is done with the standard page view tracker, but you have to have all of the data in the dataLayer BEFORE the page view tracker fires. In a standard GTM implementation, the page view tracker fires as soon as the GTM container code is finished loading. The loading order in your thank you page should be as follows:

1. Declare dataLayer with all e-commerce information. Do not use
   dataLayer.push(). You should have all of the necessary data to
   populate dataLayer in your e-commerce system before the the page
   loads. Retrieve this data and put it into dataLayer.
2. Load your GTM container. This is the standard code provided by GTM.

All of this should be done immediately after the `<body>` open tag and not at the bottom of the page code before the `</body>` close tag.

If you can not populate dataLayer before the GTM container code loads, then you will have to fire a GA event tag on gtm.dom to carry the transaction data.

It's likely that your inconsistent firing of the transaction data is due to the race conditions caused by improper GTM implementation.

Comment: That is correct - I don't have all my data until later in the page. So, I guess that brings me to the point of how to "fire a GA event on the gtm.dom to carry..." Any pointers as to where to find out how to do this?

Comment: If you're doing a response.write() as stated above, why can't you do the response.write before you include the GTM container code?

Comment: I have inherited this from others and the logic within the page branches as it renders and data is not exposed until it is ready to render it - not the best I know. Rebuilding the whole page carries to much risk. Thus, having the GTM at the bottom before the end of the body does then meet the "before gtm container" criteria in principle.

Comment: Create a GA Tag of Track Type Transaction in GTM. Call it Transaction Complete or something similar. Give it a rule that fires only on the URL of your thank you page and only fires when the gtm.dom event fires. https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/3002596?hl=en

Comment: That is how I've got the tag setup. I am looking at the article you quoted - I see that there is a new version available that incorporates a trigger for "DOM Ready" - might look into that further.

Comment: Dom ready exists in the old version as well. That is gtm.dom.

Comment: As described in the question:- The Setup: 
     GTM Created Tag "Booking Value Transaction" - Type=Universal Analytics, Enabled Display Advert Features, Track Type = Transaction Added 2 Rules Rule Name = "BookNow" - Conditions {{url}} contains thankyou + {{event}} contains gtm.dom